# Why doesn't iPhone 8 have Face ID?

Tags: iphone, face-id

I want to ask why iPhone X has Face ID where iPhone 8 or earlier iPhones do not? Why can't Face ID feature be imported to iPhone 8, 7 etc. via updates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hardware. Go to Apple's iPhone X page, specifically the [page on Face ID](https://www.apple.com/iphone-x/#face-id).

> TrueDepth Camera
>   A tiny space houses some of the most sophisticated technology we’ve ever developed, including the cameras and sensors that enable Face ID.
>
> The TrueDepth camera system is composed of multiple innovative technologies. Working together in real time, they use a detailed depth map of your face to recognize you in an instant.
>
> Dot Projector
>   More than 30,000 invisible dots are projected onto your face to build your unique facial map.
>
> Infrared Camera
>   An infrared camera reads the dot pattern, captures an infrared image, then sends the data to the Secure Enclave in the A11 Bionic chip to confirm a match.
>
> Flood Illuminator
>   Invisible infrared light helps identify your face even when it’s dark.

It's not simple a software update. To add Face ID to other iOS devices would require a hardware upgrade.